# Conditions which SignInAnonymouslyAsync() returns the same user

Tags: firebase-authentication

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync()
```

It is a question about anonymous user (FirebaseUser) returned by the above function.

I am creating iOS and Android applications with Unity.
Is the "FirebaseUser" returned by "SignInAnonymouslyAsync()" always the same as long as a user is using the same mobile device?
Also, what is the condition that the returned "Firebase User" is always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user is always the same unless the app is uninstalled and reinstalled, the app's private data was cleared, or you sign out the user.  In any of those cases, the previous anonymous user token is lost and a new one is generated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!
I was able to understand the behavior of SignInAnonymouslyAsync().
Thank you very much!!